# Configure Mulesoft shared distribution memory

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-cluster

I am working on Mulesoft application which I have deployed in Mule servers of two different physical machines.The servers are binded together to form a cluster.

In clustering mode, the servers are said to share common distributed memory such that if one machine goes down,the other machine takes up the task of the first machine.So,they maintain common distributed memory between them.

Is there any way to configure the memory for the common distributed memory the cluster leverages? 
As the traffic/number of applications gets added up,I guess,there will be need to lift the threshold memory up for the respective cluster.

Or if not,do we ever have to modify the memory volume at all that Mulesoft cluster uses ?

Please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In clustered scenarios all object stores are replaced with clustered object stores. Clustered object stores use the shared memory grid created by the clustering code to persist information (meaning that there is no file system level persistence), in case of an outage with a node, other nodes in the cluster should remain active and maintain the OS information in the shared memory grid, thus making the persistence in the file system unnecessary

Additionally, since object stores use the name of the application as part of storage information, if you want to keep them across re-deployments, the newly deployed application must have the same name as the previous one. Please see below as a reference:

Scenario a:
1. Current application name: test
2. New application name: test
- Object store values will be preserved from 1 to 2.

Scenario b:
1. Current application name: test-v1
2. New application name: test-v2
- Object store values will not be preserved from 1 to 2.

Note, In-memory store – Prior to Mule 3.5.0, in-memory store was the default. As of Mule 3.5.0, persistent store is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Mulesoft has a felicity of active-active server here we need not to bother about which server has to work when one server is down another will work. The memory is similar to jvm memory consumption.